# Publishing topics in specific widget methods with Dojo

Tags: events, templates, dojo

I would like to be able to have specific topics published when something happens to a _Templated object.
Right now, I am simply creating widgets mixing in an extra bit:

```
[...]
return declare('hotplate.hotDojoAuth.LoginForm', [_WidgetBase, _TemplatedHooksMixin, _TemplatedMixin, _WidgetsInTemplateMixin ], {
```

_TemplatedHooksMixin simply emits:

```
define([
  'dojo/_base/declare',
  'dojo/_base/lang',
  'dojo/topic',

  ], function(
    declare
  , lang
  , topic

  ){
    return  declare(null, {

      templatedHooks: true,

      constructor: function(){
        this.templatedHooks = true;
        topic.publish('hotplate/hotHooks/constructor', this);
      },

      buildRendering: function(){
        topic.publish('hotplate/hotHooks/buildRendering/before', this);
        this.inherited(arguments);
        topic.publish('hotplate/hotHooks/buildRendering/after', this);
      },

      destroyRendering: function(){
        topic.publish('hotplate/hotHooks/destroyRendering/before', this);
        this.inherited(arguments);
        topic.publish('hotplate/hotHooks/destroyRendering/after', this);
      },

      postCreate: function(){
        topic.publish('hotplate/hotHooks/postCreate/before', this);
        this.inherited(arguments);
        topic.publish('hotplate/hotHooks/postCreate/after', this);
      },

      startup: function(){
        topic.publish('hotplate/hotHooks/startup/before', this);
        this.inherited(arguments);
        topic.publish('hotplate/hotHooks/startup/after', this);
      },

      destroy: function(){
        topic.publish('hotplate/hotHooks/destroy/before', this);
        this.inherited(arguments);
        topic.publish('hotplate/hotHooks/destroy/after', this);
      }

    });
  }
);
```

Questions:

1) The code is repeated, mainly because it uses "this", "arguments", "inherited", which all scream "Don't duck with me!" (especially this.inherited). . Any hints on making one function with a simple parameter?

2) Is this a half-sane way of doing it? The idea is to allow other widgets, unrelated to my library, to change the contents of a _Templated widget.

3) If this IS a good path (comments?), do you think the way I am calling the paths is sane?

Thank you!

Merc.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should look at using `dojo/aspect`

http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.8/dojo/aspect.html

```
constructor: function(){
    this.templatedHooks = true;

    var methodsToDecorate = ["buildRendering", "destroyRendering", ...];
    array.forEach(methodsToDecorate, function(methodName) {
        aspect.before(this, methodName, function(deferred){
            topic.publish('hotplate/hotHooks/' + methodName + '/before', this);
        });
        aspect.after(this, methodName, function(deferred){
            topic.publish('hotplate/hotHooks/' + methodName + '/after', this);
        });
    });

    topic.publish('hotplate/hotHooks/constructor', this);
},
```

Comment: I will give this a go. However, I am especially worried about that this.inherited(arguments) in my functions, as well as the fact that "this" in `aspect.before(this, methodName, function(deferred){` is going to be methodName (the function) rather than the object itself.